# Controller and throttle wiring question

Tags: electric-bike

I'm in the process of wiring my key lock throttle to the controller and coming up at a loss for how to wire them. I've scoured the internet and haven't found an answer that helps me. I know I'm getting power to the throttle because the volt display powers on when battery is connected. From what I have read, the blue wire from the throttle connects to the key ignition wire from the controller and this turns the controller on. However, when I turn the key and twist the throttle, nothing happens. If someone could please confirm the wiring for me? [image: Controller[![][1]]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is a kitset you're retrofitting to a normal bike?  Might have to ask the kitset supplier/manufacturer.     That's a lot of wires!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user describes having a twist throttle.  Bicycles don't have twist throttles, this question is probably referencing a moped

Comment: That's interesting because my parents both have e-bikes by Pedego and have twist throttles. It gives the option for peddle assist or have full assist like a motorbike/moped/scooter/etc.

Comment: These are legal in some parts of the world and technically illegal but nobody cares until someone dies in some others. Anyway, nobody knows and this is more electronics or manual reading question than about bicycles.